# Jumping to different route chain in Express

Tags: regex, node.js, express

I discovered the fairly useful device in Express to jump to a new chain of middleware in Express

say we have this:

```
router.post('/', function(req,res,next){

   next();

}, function(req,res,next){

   next('route');  //calling this will jump us down to the next router.post call

}, function(req,res,next){ //not invoked

   next();  

}, function(err,req,res,next){

      //definitely not invoked
});



router.post('/', function(req,res,next){  //this gets invoked by the above next('route') call

   next();


}, function(err,req,res,next){

});
```

I could see where this might be useful and am trying to figure out how it works.

The problem that I see is this solution just seems to kick the can down the road a bit. What I want is to be able to call next('route:a') or next('route:b') so I can select which handler to invoke by name, not just the next one in the list.

As an example, I have this:

```
router.post('/', function (req, res, next) {  //this is invoked first
    console.log(1);
    next('route');
});

router.post('/', function (req, res, next) {  //this is invoked second
    console.log(2);
    next('route');
});

router.use('foo', function (req, res, next) {  //this gets skipped
    console.log(3);
});

router.post('bar', function (req, res, next) {  //this get skipped
    console.log(4);
});

router.post('/', function(req,res,next){  // this gets invoked third
    console.log(5);
 });
```

What I am looking for is a way to invoke "foo" and "bar" by name. Is there a way to do that with Express?

Comment: In addition to replies below, have a look into this  https://github.com/dizlexik/express-reverse and this library https://github.com/hrajchert/express-shared-routes

Answer (score 7):

Actually `next('route')` goest to next route but your url is `/` not `foo` so it skips that and moves on to next routes, till it finds a matching one , which happens at last case and you get `5` in console

If u want you can just change `req.url` to something like `foo` or whatever, then it will enter that route (and it won't skip middleares for that route) or you can do something like `res.redirect` then call will come again from client

```
router.post('/', function (req, res, next) {  //this is invoked second
    console.log(2);
    req.url="foo";
    next('route');
});
```

Actually @zag2art approach is good , At the end of day you have to keep ur code smart enough to handle your cases elegantly. Express doesn't provide anything as such to skip to a particualr route

Comment: I haven't tested this yet, but so far it seems like the most reasonable answer, regardless of whether there's a valid use case or not (which I believe there is). req.originalUrl will stay intact, and if you can reset req.url and control the flow of the middleware that way, then that provides a lot of possiblities.

Comment: well i tested it before posting , and if u want we can write a wrapper module on next to extend it's functionality to `next('route:a')` . I tried something here https://github.com/aishwat/shonen_jump but it doesn't work as expected , u may try it

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you have just something like this:

```
router.post('/', function (req, res, next) {  //this is invoked first
    console.log(1);
    foo(req, res, next);
});

router.post('/', function (req, res, next) {  //this is invoked second
    console.log(2);
    bar(req, res, next);
});

function foo(req, res, next) { 
    console.log(3);
};

function bar(req, res, next) { 
    console.log(4);
};

router.post('/', function(req,res,next){  // this gets invoked third
    console.log(5);
});
```

Comment: simply because you have  jumped out of the middleware and then can't invoke any specialized middleware after jumping out